# TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable Python/django

Tags: django, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a test case that is returning the following error.

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 1255, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/dir/to/project/Anwser/qanda/tests.py", line 29, in test_elasticsearch_upsert_on_save
    q.save()
  File "/dir/to/project/Anwser/qanda/models.py", line 40, in save
    elasticsearch.upsert(self)
  File "/dir/to/project/Anwser/qanda/service/elasticsearch.py", line 54, in upsert
    doc_type = question_dict['_type']
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is the function that lives inside `elasticsearch.py`

```
def upsert(question_model):
    client = get_client()
    question_dict = question_model.as_elastic_search_dict
    doc_type = question_dict['_type']
    del question_dict['_id']
    del question_dict['_type']
    response = client.update(
        settings.ES_IDENX,
        question_dict,
        id=question_model.id,
        body={
            'doc': doc_type,
            'doc_as_upsert': True,
        }
    )
    return response
```

As i have read other threads about similar issues, i came to a conclusion that the problem relies in **__getItem(self)__** of the object that is calling the function.
Since the function should return a dictionary, it returns a method instead.

Here is the function inside of model.

```
def as_elastic_search_dict(self):
        return {
            '_id': self.id,
            '_type': 'doc',
            'text': '{}\n{}'.format(self.title, self.question),
            'question_body': self.question,
            'title': self.title,
            'id': self.id,
            'created': self.created,
        }
```

**TestCase:**

```
class QuestionSaveTestCase(TestCase):
    """
        Testing Question.save()
    """

    @patch('qanda.service.elasticsearch.Elasticsearch')
    def test_elasticsearch_upsert_on_save(self, ElasticSearchMock):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username='unittest',
            password='unittest'
        )
        question_title = 'Unit test'
        question_body = 'Some unit test'
        q = Question(title=question_title,
                     question=question_body,
                     user=user)
        q.save()

        self.assertIsNotNone(q.id)
        self.assertTrue(ElasticSearchMock.called)
        mock_client = ElasticSearchMock.return_value
        mock_client.update.assert_called_once_with(
            settings.ES_IDENX,
            id=q.id,
            body={
                'doc': {
                    '_type': 'doc',
                    'text': '{}\n{}'.format(question_title, question_body),
                    'question_body': question_body,
                    'title': question_title,
                    'id': q.id,
                    'created': q.created,
                },
                'doc_as_upsert': True,
            }
        )
```

What are all the possible usecase's that can be used to solve this problem? If my understanding was correct, then i should override **__getItem(self)__** to return the dictionary. If that is correct how should i implement **__getItem(self)__** and if it will be configured to return the dictionary, how will it affect the object lifecycle in total?

Comment: you need to execute the method, you are missing the parenthesis after the method name, change `question_model.as_elastic_search_dict` to `question_model.as_elastic_search_dict()`.

Comment: @NalinDobhal God bless you.

Comment: @NalinDobhal i don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

you need to execute the method, you are missing the parenthesis after the method name, change `question_model.as_elastic_search_dict` to `question_model.as_elastic_search_dict()`.

So your function will be:

```
def upsert(question_model):
    client = get_client()
    question_dict = question_model.as_elastic_search_dict()
    doc_type = question_dict['_type']
    del question_dict['_id']
    del question_dict['_type']
    response = client.update(
        settings.ES_IDENX,
        question_dict,
        id=question_model.id,
        body={
            'doc': doc_type,
            'doc_as_upsert': True,
        }
    )
    return response
```